# How to remove new option 'Create testName run configuration from context' from single test run in IntelliJ IDEA v. 2019.3?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA v. 2019.3 new 4th option appeared: "Create 'testName' run configuration from context" when trying to run single test:

1. Run 'testName'
2. Debug 'testName'
3. Run 'testName' with Coverage
4. **Create 'testName'...**

I used to choice last option "Run 'testName' with Coverage" and now new option is annoying.
Is there a way to remove/hide it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/run_configurations/run_configuration_management.html

Comment: @Kootli thanks, but I don't see that settings. If you mean what is possible to edit code, I'm not sure after that I can run IDEA.